# C++: How to use same datatype with two different names in two different overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, overloading

I have the following declaration to distinct that it uses different operations in my code:

```
typedef unsigned int SOMEIDTYPE;
```

Now when i create two overloaded functions:

```
string something(const unsigned int &val){ ... itoa(val) ... }
string something(const SOMEIDTYPE &val){ ... IDTABLE[val] ... }
```

I get error: `error C2084: function 'std::string something(const unsigned int &)' already has a body`

So, How can i overload this function to use those two different datatypes distinctively, and perform different operations as seen above?

**Edit:** The reason for overloading is that i am calling this function inside a template function.

Comment: Since your two methods appear to have different behavior, you probably  shouldn't overload. Using two different function names would be acceptable.

Comment: how do i use two different function names in a template? actually, now i am, because i cant get this to work since ++ operator is weird. Nonetheless, im still trying to make this work.

Comment: typedef does not create a new type. It merely introduce an alternative name for some other typw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `typedef` only creates a nickname -- it doesn't create a new type.

If you really want to do something like this, then you need to create a new type.  You could create a class for this purpose, but in order for that class to behave like an `int`, you'd need to do some work:

```
class SOMEIDTYPE
{
public:
  SOMEIDTYPE();
  SOMEIDTYPE(const int&);
  SOMEIDTYPE& operator=(const SOMEIDTYPE&);
  operator int() const;
private:
  int val_;
};
```

Now you can overload on `SOMEIDTYPE`

Comment: It's actually not all that bad, once you've done it once or twice and figured out all the little gotchas.

Comment: Is it val_ or _val? someone else posted similar approach, but he used _val

Comment: using `_val` is unadvisable, because the standard reserves identifier starting with an underscore.  But it can be pretty much anything you want.  `val_`, `m_val` and `ILikePizza` are all fine.

Comment: its creating tons of errors... do i have to write down all the possible operations, like ++ -- /= *=  there? or is there some shortcut... i would like to see a list of how all those should be declared as well so i dont write bad code

Comment: Yeah, you have to write all the operators you use.

Comment: im getting `possible loss of data` warnings, is there some way to hide these by using this class somehow? with typedef it never warned about those.

Comment: how i make these ++ etc work? could you provide example in the code you gave ?

Answer (score 5):

Use a strong typedef.  Boost has one.  Standard typedef is insufficient for this req.

Answer (score 4):

They're not distinct data types, a `typedef` does not create a distinct type, it creates an alias. Hence, to the compiler, it sees two functions with the same name that take a single argument, both the same type.

Comment: Okay, so how do i create distinct datatypes so i can make this work?

Comment: @Newbie - @Noah Roberts' suggestion works, using [`<boost/strong_typedef.hpp>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp). But I wonder if you're overloading functions that don't share the same behavior guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The compiler uses the method signature to decide which one to call.  If the methods have identical functions, the compiler can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, this doesn't work because `typedef` only creates a new name for the same type.

There are two ways you can work around this:

1. Give the overloads different names:

   ```
   string somethingInt(...)...
   string somethingID(...)...
   ```
2. Create a new class/struct with the new name. To make it work like an integer, you can overload various operators.

   ```
   struct SOMEIDTYPE {
       private: int _val;
       public:
       SOMEIDTYPE & operator=(const SOMEIDTYPE &rhs) {
           _val = rhs._val;
       }
       SOMEIDTYPE & operator=(const int &rhs) {
           _val = rhs;
       }
       //etc.
   }
   ```

Comment: may i ask why is the same `SOMEIDTYPE & operator=` twice there? do i have to make every possible combination to `int` vs `SOMEIDTYPE` ?

Comment: @John: Yes, in a global scope (which this isn't)

Comment: @Newbie: in this hypothetical situation, SOMEIDYUPE isn't `typedef`'d to int, it's separate.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would have to wrap the second type in a class of some kind, off the top of my head, something like:

```
struct SOMEIDTYPE
{
    operator unsigned int&() { return _i;};
    SOMEIDTYPE(unsigned int ui):  _i(ui) {;};
    private:
    unsigned int _i;
};
```

That creates a distinct type that you can use as you expect. (BTW, my C++ is a little rusty, so the syntax might be a little off above.)